# Is it possible to hardcode CSS link in django?

Tags: django

I have an django project and want to hardcode a link to CSS (I **do not want** to use STATIC_FILES...etc). The reason is because I want to be able to click index.html and it will work on browser (including getting the css file).

I put both *index.html* and *index.css* in the same directory and added this line in index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./index.css"/>
```

When I double-click *index.html*, it imports *index.css* perfectly.

However, when I load it with the django development server and open via browser, it does not import the *index.css*.

What should be done so that *index.html* takes the *index.css*?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a static folder?

Comment: More to the point, why do you want to use Django? Your requirements are much more suited to a static site served directly by Apache or nginx.

Comment: The reason I dont want to use STATIC is because O need to give some files to 3rd party and they do not use Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the browser uses a directory based approach.

Say your template directory looks like this:

```
/home/yura/project/templates/
                            → index.html
                            → index.css
```

When opening index.html with your browser it plainly looks for index.css in the same directory, thus for `/home/yura/project/templates/index.css`.

Now when you run the development server it's not directory based anymore. There's the `urls.py` file that specifies where each path leads to.
You probably have a route `/` that leads to `index.html` even though `index.html` isn't called nothing. You could also add a route `/blog/` that may lead to `blog_home.html` even though the file is called `blog_home.html`.
Every url that enters django is routed through the `urls.py` file.
This is one of django's core concepts. URLs should be user-typable and readable without cruft as `.php`, `.html` and so on that comes from directory based approaches like PHP or CGI.

Since you haven't defined a route called `/index.css` thus `index.css` isn't found.
If the thing you are doing is a one-off your best bet would be to just add a route to `/index.css` that delivers `index.css`.

Otherwise there is no way of doing this, since django isn't directory based, as pointed out above.

You might then want to think about why exactly you want to be able to open the raw html file directly in the browser too, since it makes the django templating language entirely useless for you, thus you can't do anything variable, loop and logic related and are stuck with basic html where you, instead of the django-dev server could just as well use a simple http-server instead.

Comment: Great, that spells some light. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Christopher Schäpers works nicely, I'd like to extend her answer by showing how you may actually do what she suggests.

Let's say you have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/index.css"/>
```

which means the browser is requesting to `localhost:8000/index.css`, so in your root `urls.py` file, you add something like this

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse

def css_path(request):  # This is basically a "view"
    path = settings.BASE_DIR / 'index.css'  # For earlier Django version: os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'index.css')
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        content = f.read()
    return HttpResponse(content, content_type='text/css')

urlpatterns = [
    # ... (your other url patterns)
    path('index.css', css_path)
]
```

NOTE: Remember to set the `content_type` keyword argument correctly base on what you are serving (Example: `application/javascript` for `.js`, `image/png` for `.png`, .etc).